# How to use resourceTimeline with react fullcalendar?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to create a react fullcalendar with resource timeline,

My code is:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline';

render() {
                    <FullCalendar className="mb-4" 
                        plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin]} events={this.state.events} 
                        resourceAreaHeaderContent="Rooms" resources={this.state.resources}  
                        initialView='resourceTimelineWeek'/>
                    
            
        )
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this error :

[image]

How can I fix it to using resources timeline with react fullcalendar ?

Comment: Why have you tagged two versions of fullCalendar? Which one are you actually using here?

Comment: I edit my post @ADyson